# Array is empty when accessed later in code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a handleClick method that calls `this.pathAnimation(node);`

```
    animateNext(node) {
        console.log(this.state);
        if (this.state.animatedKeyCounter > this.state.animatedNodesKeys.length) {
            console.log(this.state.animatedNodesKeys)
            this.setState({ animatedKeyCounter: 0});
            this.spawnNode(node);
            return;
        }
        console.log("test: " + this.state.animatedNodesKeys[0]);
        let currNode = this[`nodeRef${this.state.animatedNodesKeys[this.state.animatedKeyCounter]}`].current;
        this.setState(prevState => { return { animatedKeyCounter: prevState.animatedKeyCounter + 1 } });
        (node.value >= currNode.state.value) ? currNode.animateGreen() : currNode.animateRed();
    }

    pathAnimation(node) {
        let nodeBinaryString = Number(node.key).toString(2);
        const keysArray = [];
        for (let index = 1; index < nodeBinaryString.length; index++) {
            let currentBinaryString = nodeBinaryString.slice(0, index);
            let currentKey = parseInt(currentBinaryString, 2);
            keysArray.push(currentKey);
        }

        this.setState({ animatedNodesKeys: keysArray });
        this.animateNext(node);
    }
```

First, pathAnimation is called from the `handleClick` method which populates the array, `animatedNodesKeys`, and stores it in `this.state`

After that, it calls animateNext(node) which accesses `this.state`

I would expect to see an array filled with some values, but when I check it in the console it's an empty array. It is also important to note that I know for a fact that the array `animatedNodesKeys` gets filled because if I access it `render()` it gives me an array with some values.

My only guess is that for some reason when animateNext(node) is called, the array has still not been set in state or maybe the values that should be there have not been calculated yet. However, animateNext(node) is called after all the code regarding the array, so how could this happen?

Comment: "My only guess is that for some reason when animateNext(node) is called, the array has still not been set in state" yes, this is correct because `setState()` is asyncronous. See the documentation for `setState()` for ways to guarantee `animateNext()` is called after state is actually set.

Comment: It's most likely an asynchronous 'issue'.  Set state allows to do 'something else' as part of the call and the second argument is called after the state has been set.  E.g. this.setState({ animatedNodesKeys: keysArray }, console.log(this.state));.  You might have to check the syntax of that though, but it should show the state immediately after being set.